# How do I set up an API request for my login?

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest

I have a login and registration with username and password fields created with Swift. I need to attach it to the API below. When I hit register it should create a new user. When I login, it should create and store the access token. After login or registration, I am taken to a tableview which displays myself (current user) as well as all the other users in the tableView. I can edit or delete the users in the tableView. How do I do this? Ay information about this would be very helpful since I have limited knowledge with REST APIs. That is a fake URI for example. Thank you!

## API Reference

URIs relative to: `https://myloginapi.com/api/v1` - mock URI

---

#### auth.token

---

`Create` new `access_token` for user and returns it.

Request

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Path         | `POST` /auth/access_token                            |
| Headers      | ~~(empty)~~                                          |
| Body         | `JSON` {"name":"`(username)`","pass":"`(password)`"} |
```

Response

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Body         | `JSON` {"data":"`access_token`"}                     |
```

#### user.get

---

`Get` one user by `id` and returns its data.

Request

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Path         | `GET` /user/`(id)`                                   |
| Headers      | Authorization: `(access_token)`                      |
| Body         | ~~(empty)~~                                          |
```

Response

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Body         | `JSON` {"data":`user`}                               |
```

#### user.update

---

`Update` one user by `id` using `request body` and returns its data.

Request

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Path         | `PUT` /user/`(id)`                                   |
| Headers      | Authorization: `(access_token)`                      |
| Body         | `JSON` {"name":"`(username)`","pass":"`(password)`"} |
```

Response

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Body         | `JSON` {"data":`user`}                               |
```

#### user.create

---

`Create` one new user using `request body` and returns its data.

Request

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Path         | `POST` /user                                         |
| Headers      | ~~(empty)~~                                          |
| Body         | `JSON` {"name":"`(username)`","pass":"`(password)`"} |
```

Response

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Body         | `JSON` {"data":`user`}                               |
```

#### user.delete

---

`Delete` one user by `id` and returns an empty response.

Request

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Path         | `DELETE` /user/`(id)`                                |
| Headers      | Authorization: `(access_token)`                      |
| Body         | ~~(empty)~~                                          |
```

Response

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Body         | ~~(empty)~~                                          |
```

#### user.list

---

`List` all users and returns a collection.

Request

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Path         | `GET` /user                                          |
| Headers      | Authorization: `(access_token)`                      |
| Body         | ~~(empty)~~                                          |
```

Response

```
| Param        | Value                                                |
| ------------ | ---------------------------------------------------- |
| Body         | `JSON` {"data":[`users`]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Alamofire.

Sample request would be :

```
Alamofire.request("https://myloginapi.com/api/v1").responseJSON { response in
    print(response.request)  // original URL request
    print(response.response) // HTTP URL response
    print(response.data)     // server data
    print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

    if let JSON = response.result.value {
        print("JSON: \(JSON)")
    }
}
```

For details check their doc: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Answer (score 0):

You can use URLSession

```
    let urlconfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    urlconfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 20
    urlconfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60
    let session = Foundation.URLSession(configuration: urlconfig, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string:"https://myloginapi.com/api/v1")) // Set Url here

    request.httpMethod = "POST" //(can set GET/POST)
    request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

    let paramString = String(format:"name=%@&pass=%@",username,password) //Set Parameter string here
    request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        (data, response, error) in

        do {
            if data == nil
            {
                //Failure
            }
            else
            {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? NSDictionary {

                    print(json) // Json response from server
            }
       }
 }
```